# What type of PDE's can one solve using Fourier Transforms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

The question is really in the title. I have been seeing many examples of PDE's (heat equation on an infinite domain for example) being solved using Fourier transforms (FT). However, I have been unable to find a theory that says which type of PDE's can be solved by FT. So, my questions would be:

1. What does mathematical theory say regarding the type of PDE's that can be solved by FT?
2. Is the following PDE solvable by FT : $c \cdot \varphi_{EE} + f(E) \cdot \varphi_{E} + g(E) \cdot \varphi + \varphi_{x} = 0 $, where $\varphi = \varphi(E,x)$, $E \in (-\infty,+\infty)$, $ x \in (0,\infty)$, $\varphi_{EE}=\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial E^2}$ and $\varphi_{x}=\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}$ and $c = constant$
3. If the above equation is not solvable by Fourier Transforms, what other methods (aside from numerical solutions) are applicable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Generally speaking you will run into troubles if you perform the fourier-transform with respect to the $E$ variable since the functions $f$ and $g$ depend on $E$ (this will lead to convolutions of your unknown function). If I were you I would try a laplace transform in $x$ and solve the resulting ODE, then transform back.

Comment: For the 2. part: what type of BC do you impose at $x=0$?

Comment: I would impose $\varphi(E,0) = f(E) = \delta(E)$. However, other conditions might also work. For example $\varphi(E,0) = const$.

Comment: Wait, so you have specific choices for the functions (or rather distributions) $f$and $g$?

Comment: Yes. $f(E) = aE^k $ and $g(E) = \frac{df}{dE} = akE^{k-1}$. I realize now that in my previous reply I identified the condition $\varphi(E,0)=f(E)$. This $f(E)$ is not the same as the one from the differential equation